# reading images with matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, scikit-learn

So I was playing with : http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_digits_classification.html#example-classification-plot-digits-classification-py

And I tried to load an image from my disk, I drawed a number in a 8x8 png image using paint.

the scikit-learn images look like that :

```
[[  0.   0.   5.  13.   9.   1.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.  13.  15.  10.  15.   5.   0.]
 [  0.   3.  15.   2.   0.  11.   8.   0.]
 [  0.   4.  12.   0.   0.   8.   8.   0.]
 [  0.   5.   8.   0.   0.   9.   8.   0.]
 [  0.   4.  11.   0.   1.  12.   7.   0.]
 [  0.   2.  14.   5.  10.  12.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   6.  13.  10.   0.   0.   0.]]
```

where 0 is white and the grater the value the darker the pixel is.
When I load an image I get this :

```
[[[ 1.          1.          1.        ]
  [ 1.          1.          1.        ]
  [ 1.          1.          1.        ]
  [ 0.85882354  0.85882354  0.85882354]
  [ 0.14901961  0.14901961  0.14901961]
  [ 1.          1.          1.        ]
  [ 1.          1.          1.        ]
  [ 1.          1.          1.        ]]

 [[ 1.          1.          1.        ]
  [ 1.          1.          1.        ]
  [ 0.56862748  0.56862748  0.56862748]
  [ 0.22745098  0.22745098  0.22745098]
  [ 1.          1.          1.        ]
  [ 1.          1.          1.        ]
  [ 1.          1.          1.        ]
  [ 1.          1.          1.        ]]

 [[ 1.          1.          1.        ]
  [ 0.9254902   0.9254902   0.9254902 ]
  [ 0.13725491  0.13725491  0.13725491]
  [ 1.          1.          1.        ]
  [ 1.          1.          1.        ]
  [ 1.          1.          1.        ]
  [ 1.          1.          1.        ]
  [ 1.          1.          1.        ]]

 [[ 1.          1.          1.        ]
  [ 0.53725493  0.53725493  0.53725493]
  [ 0.63137257  0.63137257  0.63137257]
  [ 0.62352943  0.62352943  0.62352943]
  [ 0.97254902  0.97254902  0.97254902]
  [ 1.          1.          1.        ]
  [ 1.          1.          1.        ]
  [ 1.          1.          1.        ]]

 [[ 1.          1.          1.        ]
  [ 0.36078432  0.36078432  0.36078432]
  [ 0.18431373  0.18431373  0.18431373]
  [ 0.72941178  0.72941178  0.72941178]
  [ 0.07843138  0.07843138  0.07843138]
  [ 0.86274511  0.86274511  0.86274511]
  [ 1.          1.          1.        ]
  [ 1.          1.          1.        ]]

 [[ 1.          1.          1.        ]
  [ 0.29411766  0.29411766  0.29411766]
  [ 1.          1.          1.        ]
  [ 1.          1.          1.        ]
  [ 0.42352942  0.42352942  0.42352942]
  [ 0.80000001  0.80000001  0.80000001]
  [ 1.          1.          1.        ]
  [ 1.          1.          1.        ]]

 [[ 1.          1.          1.        ]
  [ 0.19607843  0.19607843  0.19607843]
  [ 0.96470588  0.96470588  0.96470588]
  [ 0.90980393  0.90980393  0.90980393]
  [ 0.08627451  0.08627451  0.08627451]
  [ 1.          1.          1.        ]
  [ 1.          1.          1.        ]
  [ 1.          1.          1.        ]]

 [[ 1.          1.          1.        ]
  [ 0.96862745  0.96862745  0.96862745]
  [ 0.28627452  0.28627452  0.28627452]
  [ 0.35686275  0.35686275  0.35686275]
  [ 1.          1.          1.        ]
  [ 1.          1.          1.        ]
  [ 1.          1.          1.        ]
  [ 1.          1.          1.        ]]]
```

Is there a built in function to convert it in a format similar to scikit-learn images? or should I write my own convertion function?

Could someone explain what imread output means? I have 8 8x3 2D arrays, I can't figure out what it is.

the documentation says that is MxN but I don't know what MxN means. http://matplotlib.org/api/image_api.html#matplotlib.image.imread

Thanks

## EDIT

so this is the code I made thanks to ali_m

```
from numpy import array

def loadImageFromDisk(image_path):

    def convertImreadImage(img):
        """
        Convert imread images to scikit-learn images
            -img : a 2 dimension array (regular or numpy array)
            -return : a 2 dimension numpy array where 0 is white and
                      the higher the value the darker the pixel
        """
        res = []
        for row in img:
            newRow = []
            for value in row:
                if value == 1.:
                    newRow.append(0)
                else:
                    newRow.append(math.floor((100-value*100)/5))
            res.append(newRow)
        return array(res)

    #needs to be a absolute path
    img = mpimg.imread(image_path)[:, :, 0]
    return convertImreadImage(img)
```

output for a 6 in a 8x8 png file :

```
[[  0.   0.   0.   2.  19.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   2.  20.  13.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   1.  20.  16.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.  15.  20.  20.  16.   3.   0.   0.]
 [  0.  20.  20.   1.  18.  20.   0.   0.]
 [  0.  20.   9.   0.   1.  20.   0.   0.]
 [  0.  20.   9.   2.  17.  18.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   6.  20.  20.  19.   0.   0.   0.]]
```

Comment: I do not know this format, but it is possible that the 8 arrays correspond to the rows of the image. Each element corresponds to the colors of each pixel rgb (or bgr). Besides your image seems to be composed of grayscale.
possible [[bgr][bgr]...[bgr]] for one row

Comment: You could easily vectorize that code: `img = np.abs(img - img.max())`

Comment: it would turn the 1 into 0 but the others values won't be in the same range than the training dataset (0-20)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `imread` is giving you an 8x8x3 array, where the final dimension corresponds to the red, green and blue channels (which are all identical since the image you made in Paint was grayscale). By the way, for arrays with > 2 dimensions it's much easier to tell their shape by checking their `.shape` attribute rather than printing their contents to the terminal.

To get an 8x8 array you could just index the first color channel, e.g. `im[:, :, 0]` where `im` is the 8x8x3 array returned by `imread`.